# Ускорить код Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, java-8, рефакторинг

Как я могу ускорить работу данного метода, возможно есть части кода, которые я слишком сложно реализовал, есть более простой способ?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


class Solution {
    public int firstMissingPositive(int[] nums) {
        List<Integer> positiveIntegerList = Arrays.stream(nums).distinct().filter(e -> e > 0).boxed().sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        int end = positiveIntegerList.size();
        if(end == 0 || positiveIntegerList.get(0) != 1){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(positiveIntegerList.get(end-1) == end){
            return end + 1;
        }
        else{
            int start = 0;
            int middle_index;
            while (end >= start) {
                if (end - start <= 2){
                    for (int i = start;i <= end; i++){
                        if(positiveIntegerList.get(i) != i + 1){
                            return i + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    return positiveIntegerList.get(end) + 1;
                } 
                middle_index = (start + end) / 2;
                if(positiveIntegerList.get(middle_index) == middle_index + 1){
                    start = middle_index + 1;
                }
                else{
                    end = middle_index - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что должен делать этот код?

Comment: @Эникейщик, "найти наименьшее целое положительное число которого в массиве нет". Для `1, 3, 4` ответ будет `2`.

Comment: Наиболее быстрое решение - вариант (псевдо)сортировки массива на месте за линейное время.

Comment: https://www.techiedelight.com/find-missing-number-array/

Comment: @tym32167, это другая задача.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну пусть тогда автор дополнит  вопрос описанием задачи, входа и выхода алгоритма и тд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм сортирует за `O(NlogN)`, а затем выполняет двоичный поиск за `O(logN)`. Оптимизировать поиск бесполезно, время уже упущено во время сортировки.

"Отсортировать" массив можно за линейное время. Кавычки потому что это не сортировка как таковая. Нужно так переставить элементы в массиве что элемент со значением `k` окажется в `nums[k - 1]` если `0 <= k - 1 < nums.length`. Элементы со значениями вне этого диапазона случайно распределяются на оставшиеся свободными места.

Будем идти по массиву и если встретим элемент который можно поставить на место и на его месте чужой элемент, поменяем их местами. Обмены повторяем пока элементы становятся на свои места, затем переходим к следующему индексу. Когда пройдём весь массив, окажется что все элементы, которые можно было поставить на место, уже на своих местах. Ещё один цикл ищет места без своего элемента, этот элемент и пропущен.

Алгоритм работает за линейное время, так как после каждого обмена число элементов на своих местах возрастает, значит мы может сделать не более линейного числа обменов.

```
class Solution {
    public int firstMissingPositive(int[] nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
            for (; ; ) {
                int j = nums[i];
                if (1 <= j && j <= nums.length) {
                    int k = j - 1;
                    if (nums[k] != nums[i]) {
                        int temp = nums[k];
                        nums[k] = nums[i];
                        nums[i] = temp;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
            if (nums[i] != i + 1) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return nums.length + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, выручил